# Unresolved inclusion: <stdio.h> in Eclipse kepler (Windows 8.1)

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc

I know this question has been asked a lot but I dont know what to do, an I dond understand the other responses.

I had this C code in eclipse Kepler in Linux and It worked, now on Windows 8.1 there is an error `"Unresolved inclusion: <stdio.h>"`

I read I have to put some path in `Properties -> C/C++ General -> Path and Simbols`

but what's that path in Windows?

Additional Information:

current toolchain: Cross GCC

Current builder : GNU Make Builder

Used Tools:

```
         Cross GCC Compiler

         Cross G++ Compiler

         Cross GCC Linker

         Cross G++ Linker

         Cross GCC Archiver

         Cross GCC Assembler
```

This is an image of the code(http://goo.gl/rX0yxZ) and this is the code:

```
/*
 * main.c
 */

#include <stdio.h>
//#include<unistd.h>
//#include<string.h>
#include<crc.h>

int main() {
    crcInit();
    int i;

    FILE *pFile = fopen("C:\Users\Itamar\Documents\REDES\hex", "r");
    if (!pFile) {
        printf("Error abriendo el archivo");
    }

    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(pFILE);
    fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_SET);
    printf("%i\n", size);
    unsigned int ITA[size];
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        char value;
        fread(&value,1,1, pFILE);
        ITA[i] = (unsigned int) value;
    }
    fclose(pFile);
    printf("CRCFast of ITA is: %X",crcFast2());
}
```

I am lost with this problem.

If you need more information please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Ita

PD: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: Well, if it's moaning about stdio.h, you might like to try searching for it with Windows file explorer.  When you find it, you will know its path.

Comment: OMG, there is no stdio.h in my computer, I forgot to download the libraries I supoosed that Eclipse did it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

OMG, there is no stdio.h in my computer, I forgot to download the libraries I supoosed that Eclipse did it. – Ita